# Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp returning Unauthorized Error 401 not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, urlfetch

I'm trying to send and email using a Google Doc. This is the code I'm using:

```
function sendHTMLtemp(){
const id = '1HC3ADjGE24ShOXeK_CYISGGIV7U0scJeXQ8o9oyu6vY';
const url = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/'+id+'/export?format=html';
const param ={
  mehtod : "get",
  headers : {
    "Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
  },
  muteHttpExceptions:true
 }
const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param);
Logger.log(html)
}
```

But I get this error "Unauthorized Error 401.":

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your script, if your Google Apps Script has only your showing script, I think that the scope is only `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`. If my guess is correct, I think that in your current situation, the scope might be insufficient. So, please modify your script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendHTMLtemp() {
  const id = '1HC3ADjGE24ShOXeK_CYISGGIV7U0scJeXQ8o9oyu6vY';
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/' + id + '/export?format=html';
  const param = {
    mehtod: "get",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, param);
  Logger.log(html)

  // DriveApp.getFiles(); // <--- This comment line is used for automatically detecting the scope of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly" by the script editor. So, please don't remove this comment.
}
```

- In this modification, a comment line of `// DriveApp.getFiles();` is used. This comment line is used for automatically detecting the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` by the script editor. By this, your error can be removed. So, please don't remove this comment.
- When this modified script is run, a dialog for authorizing the scopes is opened. So, please authorize the scopes. By this, the script is run.
- I think that in your situation, the scopes can also be set to the manifest file (`appsscript.json`). But, in this case, the scopes are fixed. I thought that this might not be suitable for your situation. So, I proposed to use the automatic detection of scopes by the script editor.